# Why am I getting "Geocoder is not running" error message when starting expo app?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm having an issue with the `expo-location` package when trying to get the address with `ExpoLocation.reverseGeocodeAsync()` on my expo app thats installed on real android device.

So I'm generating an android apk with the `eas build` and after installing, when I open the app I allow the Location permissions and after few seconds I'm getting the `Geocoder is not running` error message which is thrown by the `ExpoLocation.reverseGeocodeAsync()` function.

What I don't understand is that when I'm running my app with the `expo go` app my application is running normally and I'm having no issue with the locations.

I also tried to unset `android.permissions` but I also doesn't worked for me.

I will also share some code with you so you can see it what I'm doing. I'm not doing some complex things. I'm calling my `getCurrentLocation` in the `App.js` when the app is starting.

I'm using the `Expo SDK 46` version

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "***",
    "scheme": "***",
    "slug": "***",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
      "package": "com.***.***",
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      ]
    },
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "barStyle": "dark-content"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "barStyle": "dark-content"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "updates": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "***"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My function to get the current location

```
import * as ExpoLocation from 'expo-location';

export const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
  let { status } = await ExpoLocation.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

  if (status === 'granted') {
    let location = await ExpoLocation.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: ExpoLocation.LocationAccuracy.Low,
    });

    let address = await ExpoLocation.reverseGeocodeAsync({
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    });

    return address[0].city;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: did you find a sollution?